# AppCompatButton and buttonStyle

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme

I am trying to get some buttons to be use the Material Design style (in particular accentColor tinting) for Android 4.4 devices using the AppCompat library.  I have had success with the following:

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/continue_button"
            android:id="@+id/continue_button"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            style="@style/CompatButton"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>
```

where "@style/CompatButton" has "Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored" for a parent. However some of my buttons are the same but instead of declaring the style in the element, I attach the style as the default "buttonStyle" in the theme being used:

```
<style name="AppTheme">
    ...
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/CompatButton</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/flow_accent</item>
    ...
</style>
```

and

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/continue_button"
            android:id="@+id/continue_button"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>
```

These buttons are showing up with the default, non-Material stylings. This also seems to happen with ProgressBar. Can anyone see what's wrong with this and if there's a workaround without having to explicitly define the button style?

Comment: Use `buttonStyle` instead of `android:buttonStyle` (and so on) when working with AppCompat widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, that was dumb.  Obviously ThemeOverlay wipes out the previous theme, including the buttonStyle definition. For it to work we have to add the buttonStyle back in:

```
    <style name="FlowOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/CompatButton</item>
    </style>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/continue_button"
            android:id="@+id/continue_button"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:theme="@style/FlowOverlay"/>
```

though that loses much of the convenience we wanted from default button styles in the first place.